# Formatting UITableViewCell date in ViewModel

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mvvm

I'm setting a TableView and would like to know what is the proper way to set UITableViewCells with viewModel.

Let's say I've got a model:

```
class Item {
   var date: Date!
   var info: String?
}
```

and my viewModel for the main ViewController has a property which is an array of Item objects.

1. I've declared the protocol for cell's view model. Should it contain properties like `var date: String` and `var info: String` (with Item initializer, so basically formatted data that are going to be displayed inside the cell) or I should keep the Item object here?
2. Who is responsible for formatting the date inside the cell? I assume cell's view model is responsible for that but on the other hand is it efficient to have dateFormatter instance inside every ViewModel? Maybe it's better to pass the dateformatter from the other class and hold only one reference?

My main viewController (methods related to the tableView)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemCell", for: indexPath) as? ItemTableViewCell

        cell?.viewModel = viewModelForCell(at: indexPath.row)
        cell?.setupCell()
        return cell ?? UITableViewCell()
    }

    private func viewModelForCell(at index: Int) -> ItemTableViewCellRepresentable {

        let item = viewModel?.items[index]
        if let item = item {
            return ItemTableViewModel(item: item, formatter: viewModel.cellDateFormatter)
        }
        return ItemTableViewModel()
    }
```

cell's viewModel protocol:

```
protocol ItemTableViewCellRepresentable {
    var date: String { get }
    var info: String? { get }

    init(item: Item, formatter: DateFormatter)
}
```

cell's viewModel class:

```
class ItemTableViewModel: ItemTableViewCellRepresentable {

    var date: String
    var info: String?

    required init(item: Item, formatter: DateFormatter) {
        self.date = formatter.string(from: item.date)
        self.info = item.info
    }

    init() {
        self.date = ""
        self.info = ""
    }

}
```

and my cell:

```
(...)

var viewModel: ItemTableViewCellRepresentable?

    func setupCell() {
        guard let viewModel = viewModel else {
            return
        }

        dateLabel.text = viewModel.date
        descriptionLabel.text = viewModel.info ?? "no info"
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ViewModel Protocol should have `Representable` information that will display to view this concept of MVVM , ViewModel just give his view information only to display

So arrange all your MVVM like that :

**Model**:

just used to map json to data model no more

```
class Item {
    var date: Date!
    var info: String?
}
```

**CellRepresentable** :

All what needed for View , cell need `date` and `information` as `String`

```
protocol ItemTableViewCellRepresentable {
    var date: String { get }
    var info: String? { get }
    init(item: Item)
}
```

**ViewModel**   :

All Logic , API Call (DateFormatting,...etc)

`ItemTableViewModel` must have reference to Model . in MVVM  ViewModel work on Model

```
class ItemTableViewModel: ItemTableViewCellRepresentable {

    var item:Item

    var date: String {
        return item.date.getItemFullDate()
    }

    var info: String? {
        return item.info
    }

    required init(item: Item) {
        self.item = item
    }
}
```

Also in your `MainViewController`

Instead you have to convert items to cellViewModel in Maincontroller `private func viewModelForCell(at index: Int) ->`

just move  to `MainViewModel` to convert it to `CellRepresentable`

So in your `MainViewController` ViewModel should be like that

```
class MainViewModel{

    var dataSource:[CellRepresentable] = [CellRepresentable]()


    func getDataFromAPI( _ completion:(()->() ){
        // Update Data Source
        // there use map to convert Items to CellRepresentable and append to 
       datasourec array
    }
}
```

For `DatFormatter` its better to use General `extension` to Handel this for you

```
protocol Dateable {
        func getItemFullDate() -> String
        func getItemHours() -> String
    }

    extension Date: Dateable {
        var  formatter: DateFormatter { return DateFormatter() }

        /** Return a Item FullDate */
        func getItemFullDate() -> String {
            // Customize a date formatter
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
            formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

            return formatter.string(from: self)
        }

        /** Return a item shor Time hour */
        func getItemHours() -> String {
            // Customize a date formatter
            formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
            formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

            return formatter.string(from: self)
        }

        // You can add many cases you need like string to date formatter

    }
```

Comment: nice, thanks for explanation. One question though. in `class MainViewModel` datasource should be of type `[ItemTableViewCellRepresentable]` right? Because now I'm just storing an array of Item objects

Comment: Yes I give you concept , you can add key of sort in protocol as well if me is an item properties

Comment: Or sort items before mapping to CellViewModel

Comment: but does it make sense to put both model (Item) and representable properties inside the protocol? It can be used if I would like to use `didSelectRowAt:` and open a new ViewController and pass the Item, right?

Comment: TableviewModel have CellViewModel this the concept so tableviewmodels maps items to CellViewModel

Comment: So TableView data source will be CellViewModel not items

Comment: Yes, I know. But if it's an array `[CellViewModel]` then does it make sense to put `Item` inside the `CellViewModelRepresentable` protocol? It can be useful if I would like to select a cell and navigate to different view with all info about model related to this cell.

Comment: It will be cellrepresentableprotocal

Comment: View of cell will only have representable